# Dark Mode with TabView appears not to be working?

Tags: swiftui, tabview, darkmode

Converted an app over to Dark Mode with everything working except the TabView. It's white in both Light and Dark modes. I am clearly doing something wrong.

[image]

The TabView code is:

```
struct MenuView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = Tab.location  
    public enum Tab: Hashable {
            case location
            case calculate
            case install
            case results
            case about
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                ...  
            } 
            .accentColor(.yellow)                                               
            .background(Color(UIColor.label))
            .toolbarBackground(Color.clear, for: .tabBar)
        }                                                                       
    }                                                                             
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor =  UIColor.label             // UIColor.white //TabBar color
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.label           // UIColor.white
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.red     // systemGray
        UITabBar.appearance().isOpaque = false
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try removing `UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white` in `init(){...}`

Comment: That's the fix.